# Finding Max Date from "Find" Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variety of calibration tests. I keep all different types and their dates in one worksheet "wsCAL"

I want to populate the userform with the most recent date of one specific type of test, which is stored in Column C in wsCAL.

In theory, I want VBA to go to wsCAL, look thru column C and find all instances of one test type, find the most recent date(or MAX) in column B of those instances, then populate my userform with that date.

I've tried using the rangeCAL = .Find() function to find all instances of a test type in column C. This part works just fine. However, the application.worksheetfunction.Max(rangeCAL) I try to use fails. I'm guessing it is because that application function only works with worksheet ranges and not Find() ones. I'm struggling with taking my rangeCAL cells, making an array, then finding the most recent date (the MAX) of those.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'Upon opening the userform

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsHOME = wb.Worksheets("Home")
    Set wsCAL = wb.Worksheets("Bottle Calibrations")
    Set wsC1T1 = wb.Worksheets("C1T1")

    'Last Calibration Date      
        Label27.Caption = vbNullString
        With wsCAL
        Dim Cell As Range
        Dim myArray As Date
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim rangeCAL As Range
        Dim rangeDateCAL As Date

        i = 0
        Set rangeCAL = Range("C:C").Find(What:=tank, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not rangeCAL Is Nothing Then
                For Each Cell In rangeCAL
                    myArray(i) = .Range(rangeCAL.Row, "A").Value
                    i = i + 1
                Next
            Else
                MsgBox "Error: no previous Calibration dates loaded."
            End If
            rangeDateCAL = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myArray)
            rangeDateCAL = Format(rangeDateCAL, "yymmdd")

    End With
    Label27.Caption = rangeDateCAL
```

I keep getting the error message

> "Expected array"

as soon as I get to line:

```
myArray(i) = .Range(rangeCAL.Row, "B").Value
```

UPDATE:

```
Label27.Caption = vbNullString
With wsCAL
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim myArray(1 To 5) As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As Date
    Dim rangeCAL As Range
    Dim rangeDateCAL As Date

    i = 1
    Set rangeCAL = wsCAL.Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown).Address)
        For Each Cell In rangeCAL
            If Cell <> "" Then
                If Cell.Value = tank Then
                    temp = wsCAL.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value
                    myArray(i) = temp
                    i = i + 1

                End If
            End If
        Next

    rangeDateCAL = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myArray)
    rangeDateCAL = Format(rangeDateCAL, "yymmdd")

End With

    Label27.Caption = rangeDateCAL
```

I implemented this change after reading your comments. This code runs, but it fills Label27.Caption with 11/22/4613 instead of the intended 11/7/2019.

I'm assuming the date value is being altered at the MAX function step, but I'm not sure what else I can change.

Comment: Important note, `Find` only returns one cell. `rangeCAL` is not all the cells you want.

Comment: There is no brackets `()` in `myArray` declaration, that is probably where error comes from.

Comment: you need to `Redim Preserve` myArray each time through the loop. Also I think you need `Cell.Row` instead of `rangeCal.Row` in the Value assignment. Once you have the array populated you can work with it. Might be easier to populate the entire data set into the array and then loop the array to first check for the test type and then if the date is later that the one you would store in a currentMaxDate variable that date. At the end of looping the range your max date is saved in the currentMaxDate variable. Other info could be in other variables, or in a 1D Array.

Comment: BigBen is correct. these is only a single cell returned by `.Find`...

Comment: Surely you want more information than just a date of the latest test. `tank` does not appear to be defined anywhere. You should always require variable declaration. Go to Tools>Options and untick Auto Syntax Check and tick Require Variable Declaration. For existing modules need to add `Option Explicit`. Why not populate a ComboBox with all of the different (unique items) in Column C so that your user form could populate the remainder of the form with information on the latest test type. If all you want is the latest date you canget that with worksheet formulas, a helper column and filtering.

Comment: Option Explicit is present and tank is defined as a public variable. Didn't include that bit because I thought that was no brainer.

Comment: The current sheet I'm pulling from will only be used to track when calibration tests are being done. Information about the tests will be pulled from other, more comprehensive, sheets.

Comment: If the date is already formatted as you want on the worksheet then use the .Text property of the cell. All you need to do is loop the range and replace the value of a variable if the current cell's value is bigger. No need for the array at all.

Comment: Would also suggest you fully qualify your test for the null string and actually use vbNullString instead of "" `If Cell.Text<>vbNullString`

Comment: You'll error if you have more than 5 items that match tank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each Cell In rangeCAL
    If Cell.Text <> vbNullString Then
        If Cell.Text = tank Then 'assuming tank is declared a string
            If tempDate < wsCAL.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value Then
                tempDate = wsCAL.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

Label27.Caption = Format(tempDate, "yymmdd")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I implemented, per SmileyFTW's suggestion. Far simpler than anticipated. Works as intended though. Thank you SmileyFTW, and the others who commented with help.

```
Label27.Caption = vbNullString
With wsCAL
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Date
    Dim temp As Date
    Dim rangeCAL As Range

    temp = 0
    Set rangeCAL = wsCAL.Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown).Address)
        For Each Cell In rangeCAL
            If Cell <> vbNullString Then
                If Cell.Value = tank Then
                    i = wsCAL.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Text
                    If i > temp Then
                        temp = i
                    End If

                End If
            End If
        Next
End With
Label27.Caption = temp
```